# CodeIgniter to SQL Server get errror :TCP Provider: The semaphore timeout period has expired

Tags: php, sql-server, codeigniter

I want to connect my CodeIgniter app to SQL Server but I got this error message

> Error (sqlsrv_query): Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 08S01 [SQLSTATE]
> => 08S01 [1] => 121 [code] => 121 [2] => [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 10.0]TCP Provider: The semaphore timeout period has expired.
> [message] => [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 10.0]TCP Provider:
> The semaphore timeout period has expired. ) [1] => Array ( [0] =>
> 08S01 [SQLSTATE] => 08S01 [1] => 121 [code] => 121 [2] =>
> [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 10.0]Communication link failure
> [message] => [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 10.0]Communication
> link failure ) )

And this is my configuration:

```
$db['sqlsrv11']['hostname'] = "host";
    $db['sqlsrv11']['username'] = "username";
    $db['sqlsrv11']['password'] = "password";
    $db['sqlsrv11']['database'] = "database";
    $db['sqlsrv11']['dbdriver'] = "sqlsrv";
    $db['sqlsrv11']['dbprefix'] = "";
    $db['sqlsrv11']['pconnect'] = FALSE;
    $db['sqlsrv11']['db_debug'] = TRUE;
    $db['sqlsrv11']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
    $db['sqlsrv11']['cachedir'] = "";
    $db['sqlsrv11']['char_set'] = "utf8";
    $db['sqlsrv11']['dbcollat'] = "utf8_general_ci";
    $db['sqlsrv11']['swap_pre'] = '';
    $db['sqlsrv11']['autoinit'] = FALSE;
    $db['sqlsrv11']['stricton'] = FALSE;
```

And I got this error from this line

```
$query = sqlsrv_query($conn, $query_sql, array(), array("Scrollable" => SQLSRV_CURSOR_KEYSET));
            if ($query === false) {
                echo "Error (sqlsrv_query): ".print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true);
                exit;
            }
```

My SQL Server is 13, PHP 7.1 , CI 3.1.1 and I'm using sqlsrv74 dll

Please help me to fix this error. Thanks.

Comment: you might not have included the `download` library in the `application/ config/ autoload.config ` file

Answer (score 0):

The issue might be that you might not have included `$autoload['libraries'] = array('database','session');` in the autoload file residing at `application/ config/ autoload.config` .

If this has been done by you try including the following configuration for the connection:

```
 $active_group = 'default';
$query_builder = TRUE;

$db['default'] = array(
    'DNS'   => 'username=host=localhost;port=the_posrt_no;dbname=databse_name',
    'hostname' => 'localhost',
    'username' => 'your_username',
    'password' => 'pass',
    'database' => 'your_database name',
    'dbdriver' => 'mysqli',
    'port' => '5432',
    'dbprefix' => '',
    'pconnect' => FALSE,
    'db_debug' => (ENVIRONMENT !== 'production'),
    'cache_on' => FALSE,
    'cachedir' => '',
    'char_set' => 'utf8',
    'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
    'swap_pre' => '',
    'encrypt' => FALSE,
    'compress' => FALSE,
    'stricton' => FALSE,
    'failover' => array(),
    'save_queries' => TRUE
);
```

Comment: thanks for your response , after debugging for quite a while I've found the error occurs because I'm using unpivot query